# How to show all controllers and mappings in a view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a none standard Spring MVC project. Responding with XMLs. Is it possible to create a view (jsp page) showing all controllers, mappings and parameters that are accepted (required and not).

Based on answer,I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/endpoints", params="secure",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String getEndPointsInView() {
    String result = "";
    for (RequestMappingInfo element : requestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerMethods().keySet()) {

        result += "<p>" + element.getPatternsCondition() + "<br>";
        result += element.getMethodsCondition() + "<br>";
        result += element.getParamsCondition() + "<br>";
        result += element.getConsumesCondition() + "<br>";
    }
    return result;
}
```

I don't get any information from `@RequestParam`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` in Spring 3.1, you can easily browse the endpoints.

The controller :

```
@Autowire
private RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;

@RequestMapping( value = "endPoints", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String getEndPointsInView( Model model )
{
    model.addAttribute( "endPoints", requestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerMethods().keySet() );
    return "admin/endPoints";
}
```

The view :

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
<head><title>Endpoint list</title></head>
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>path</th>
    <th>methods</th>
    <th>consumes</th>
    <th>produces</th>
    <th>params</th>
    <th>headers</th>
    <th>custom</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <c:forEach items="${endPoints}" var="endPoint">
    <tr>
      <td>${endPoint.patternsCondition}</td>
      <td>${endPoint.methodsCondition}</td>
      <td>${endPoint.consumesCondition}</td>
      <td>${endPoint.producesCondition}</td>
      <td>${endPoint.paramsCondition}</td>
      <td>${endPoint.headersCondition}</td>
      <td>${empty endPoint.customCondition ? "none" : endPoint.customCondition}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also do this with Spring < 3.1, with `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` instead of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. But you won't have the same level of information.

With `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` you will only have the endpoints path,  without information about their methods, consumes, params...

Comment: It is nice, however, I do not get all information.<pre> @RequestMapping("/get")
 public @ResponseBody
 String getUsername(
   @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) int id) {
  
  return "test";
 }</pre>

Comment: getPatternsCondition is working, but all the others does not work.

Comment: I wrote this code for my own usage and it works well. This is not because `${endPoint.methodsCondition}` displays nothing it doesn't work. It's just because you don't have any method conditions for the endPoint. Moreover, `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` informations are based only on the `@RequestMapping` annotation content. If you want to see the parameter `id`, you have to had a parameter condition, something like that : `@RequestParam(value="/get", params = {"id"})`

Comment: Oki, I see. Got it working with <code>@RequestMapping</code> and params=something.  Do you know how to access the fields in <code>@RequestMapping</code> (required and optinal)? - Man, I suck at stackoverflow editing

Comment: Lol, click on help at the bottom of `Add Comment` and you will see how to pad your code snippet. Oups I made a mistake in my last comment I meant `@RequestMapping` not `@RequestParam` for the last thing. The fields in `@RequestMapping` are conditions and they are al displayed in the solution I gave you.

Comment: :-) I'll the help then. I am not using your example 100%. I'll update the question for better code reading.

Comment: +1 nice answer and _exactly_ what I was looking for. FWIW, I ended up just using a simple `return new ModelAndView("_system", "routes", requestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerMethods().keySet());` as I was using the `ModelAndView` in another method

Comment: am using spring 3.0 . is there anyway to achieve the same in spring 3.0 ??

Comment: Yes, see the bottom of my answer concerning spring version < 3.1