# Is their an existing tool to generate sitemap and robots txt using spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, seo, spring-security, robots.txt

I have website with secured pages, and a number of public directories.

Is their a built in mechanism or existing library that geernates a sitemap and/or robots.txt based on controller request mappings and their security access levels/request types ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no built in mechanism or existing library that geernates a sitemap and/or robots.txt

But you can build it by your own: because it is possible to read the mapping.

@see: [How to show all controllers and mappings in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766800/how-to-show-all-controllers-and-mappings-in-a-view)

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating sitemaps you can make use of [Sitemapgen4j](https://code.google.com/p/sitemapgen4j/) a library to generate XML sitemaps in Java. It can quickly get you started generating valid XML sitemaps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got to use a generator for sitemap and robot.txt. I only use Google webmaster tools. You can try to check this out: 
[robotstxt generator](http://searchengineland.com/google-offers-robotstxt-generator-13653)
and
[this](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183668)