# Printing all REST service URLs during application startup

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

I have an application with REST services implemented with Spring Boot and Jersey 2.
How can I print full URLs of all available RESTful services to log during application startup?

I tried writing it from services themselves, but they are initialized only on first access.

Comment: Please support your post with code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue is here 
[How to show all controllers and mappings in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766800/how-to-show-all-controllers-and-mappings-in-a-view)
Basically after injecting `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` to your Logger Service just browse what it gives you using your favorite logger tool, system.out or slf4j :)

Comment: It's not the same nor similar, because the OP uses Jersey for the REST endpoints and not Spring MVC like in your link. RequestMappingHandlerMapping won't help because it doesn't know the Jersey endpoints.